# Jquery slider - having name/value pairs or array for the values

Tags: jquery, arrays, slider

I'm using a slider so that users can select their place in a range from 1-10 (or a similar range)

I know that i can specify the values/steps for the slider but can i have those values correspond to another?

```
i.e. 
1 = id3040 
2 = id0290
3 = id3782
```

So if they select '3' on the slider, I can get that corresponding value?

I have a survey and this will be used multiple times on the page, with the values being pulled from the db

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use an array to store the values you need, like this:

```
var values = ['id3040', 'id0290', 'id3782'];
```

Then define an event when initializing the slider to access the values stored in the array

```
stop: function(event, ui){
    console.log(values[ui.value]);
}
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/wL7Ww/